# Помогите с MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Я хочу динамически создавать сетку ( grid ) но столкнулся с некоторой проблемой связанной с MVVM

В ViewModel:

```
public ICommand InitWindow
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand((obj) =>
        {
            const int maxCamNums = 16;
            int ColumRows = (int)Math.Sqrt(maxCamNums);

            ColumnDefinition[] ColDefs = new ColumnDefinition[ColumRows]; // Массив столбцов
            RowDefinition[] RowDefs = new RowDefinition[ColumRows]; // Массив строчек

            for (int i = 0; i < ColumRows; i++)
            {
                ColDefs[i] = new ColumnDefinition(); // инициализация столбцов
                MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(ColDefs[i]); // добавляем их в основную сетку

                RowDefs[i] = new RowDefinition(); // инициализация строчек
                MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(RowDefs[i]); // добавляем их в сетку
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Тут я создал команду события инициализации окна, привязал её в XAML но проблема в том что компилятор ругается на MainGrid, он его попросту не видит

В XAML коде

```
 <Window x:Class="VMS.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VMS"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Initialized="{Binding InitWindow}">
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" ShowGridLines="true">

</Grid>
```

Может я чего-то не понимаю, подскажите пожалуйста
Я только начал учить MVVM и похоже что то не понял
Вот ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: "ругается на MainGrid" - пожалуйста, приведите точный текст ошибки.

Comment: собирать проект пробовали? Если не компилируется попробуйте "Пересобрать решение ". ПКМ по вашему решению и там увидите соответствующую кнопку.

Comment: Пересобрал, не помогло

Comment: Какой же это MVVM если вы с гридом (view) в коде (viewModel) работаете

Comment: У вас нет тут MVVM. По правилам MVVM вы не можете знать из VM слоя о том, что находится в V слое. Исходя из этого `MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add` является грубым нарушением, которое полностью сводит на нет принцип MVVM. Вот удалите все из XAML, оставьте просто `<Grid/>` и запустите проект, если будет реализован грамотно MVVM, то он запустится и будет работать (только без UI).

Comment: А по поводу ошибки, что то мне подсказывает, что `Initialized` происходит до того, как отработает `InitializeComponent();` в конструкторе окна (а он и инициализирует все контролы), но могу и ошибаться, не проверял их последовательность.

Comment: Ладно, я понял что нарушил принципы MVVM подскажите как правильно реализовать эту задачу на MVVM, пожалуйста

Comment: Стандартный Grid не очень хорошо дружит с "динамикой" и сделать подобное на нем, для новичка, довольно трудно будет. Как один из вариантов решения, вы можете использовать `ItemsControl`, который вложен в другой `ItemsControl`, как по мне это самый легкий вариант. Вот пример на [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814224/wpf-grid-with-dynamic-columns). Если вам все же нужен Grid, то там надо реализовывать так называемые `Аttached properties`, вот один из [примеров](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/) подобной реализации.